# Cylinder misfire after leak down test

Tags: misfire, tacoma, cylinder

I am getting cylinder misfire OBDII error codes after performing a cylinder leakdown test. During the test, I was turning the crankshaft to reach TDC for each cylinder and I'm now thinking whether it needed to be readjusted again (to a startup position) in order for the firing to run. The engine is on and running but slightly shaking and the check engine light is on (which is why I got the code readings). Or could moisture (it was mildly raining) have affected the connection between the ignition coils and the spark plugs?

Toyota Tacoma V6 2007.

Comment: Double check to ensure your firing order is correct. It's easy to get a couple of spark plug wires mixed up.

Comment: Check the spark plug and plug wire on the cylinder that is misfiring.

Comment: Please post the make model, engine and year of the vehicle.

Comment: Paulster, that has been ruled out for sure

Comment: I'm not sure I see the connection between a leak down and a misfire.  Seems disconnected to me.

Comment: @amphibient - Yes, your vehicle should be plug on, I'd bet, which makes it kind of hard. You need to double check the wiring going to the coils then to ensure you haven't fouled anything (possibly disconnected?). I'd double check to ensure you are getting power to every coil and to ensure every ground coming out of the coils are good as well.

Comment: Just to make sure you only rotated the crank clockwise and not back and forth?

Comment: Ben, I thought that didn't matter

Comment: How can I test the wiring? Each coil has a connector that contains i believe 4 wires. They all look alright

Comment: How can I check that I'm getting proper power to each coil ?

Comment: pin 1 on a Toyota ignition coil is power. If there's enough slack or the tensioner is weak it can cause the belt/chain to slip when rotated counter clockwise.

Comment: hey @amphibient   How's the troubleshooting going?

Comment: I fixed it. It was bad spark plugs. I just dunno why they were bad since I replaced them less than a year ago. I put iridium. Now I just put regular copper and that cleared all the codes

Comment: @amphibient please post your fix as an answer so we can move this question off the "Unanswered" stack. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't say why you needed a leakdown test in the first place. If you rotated the engine by hand in the opposite direction that it normally runs and it has a timing belt then it is possible that the valve timing may have jumped. You would have to  remove part of the covers and check that all cam timing markes line up as per the manufacturers specs. If its a long way out you could have a bent valve as a result.
Before that check that one of your HT leads isn't damaged from removing it. Test with an ohmmeter for an open circuit. As said before check the firing order.
Short out one HT lead at a time to determine which cylinder is affected, then try swapping leads if the affected cylinder changes then the lead must be faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you removed the sparking plugs to perform the test and have likely disturbed one of the connectors or possibly haven't got one of the plugs at the correct torque.

One thing I've seen in the past was someone remove a plug, accidentally drop it then refit it.  This caused a misfire because when it hit the ground, the electrode gap closed up.

Remove your plugs, check the gaps, refit them to the correct torque and make sure all of the wiring to the plugs and associated coil(s) are firmly and correctly connected.